# error: eof expected?! How to use idea and eclipse plugins together in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I use sbt `0.13`.

Both https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse and https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-idea suggest to add a line for each to `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`.

Thus my `plugins/build.sbt` looks like:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")
```

With that, sbt keeps failing with the error:

```
.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt:2: error: eof expected but ';' found.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")
^
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that settings are separated by blank lines.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? zsh: exit 130   sbt
```

Interestingly, both lines work seperately.

Is it possible to use both plugins?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [How build.sbt defines settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html#how-build-sbt-defines-settings) you need to put a blank line between Scala expressions.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.1")
# blank line here
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")
```

Note that you need SBT `0.13.0` for sbteclipse `2.3.0` and sbt-idea is currently for SBT `0.12.x`.